# C# wpf window issue

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently running into an issue with opening a new wpf window. The current program sets a boolean called confirmed to false, the program then opens a new window and passes an ID to the new window where the user will be prompted to click a yes button if they can confirm the ID is their ID(if so the boolean is set to true) or no if the ID is not their ID(if so the boolean is set to false again). The new window will then close and return to the normal window with the new value of the boolean. An if statement then runs to check the value of the boolean, if false then a message is displayed to the user, if true the customer is then moved onto a new window.

The issue I am having is the program seems to open up the new window and prompt the user as it should, however at the same time the program steps into the next if statement checking the value of boolean before the user has a change to click yes or no. So the new window will open and then the next if statement will run even though I want to wait for user input, how do I prevent this from happen, code is listed below

Code for opening new window and boolean check

```
bool confirmed == false;
int id = 1;
promptWindow = new promptWindow(id, confirmed);
```

code for new window

```
public(int id, bool confirmed)
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
}

private void btnYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //confirms the user wants to book and returns value
    bool confirmation = true;
    return confirmation;
    this.Close; 
}

private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //confirms the user doesn't want to book and returns value
    bool confirmation = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

Code for checking boolean value

```
if (confirmation == true)
{
    //adds new customer to customer as they have confirmed booking
    add.list(id);
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Booking not added");
}
```

Comment: _"...The issue I am having..."_, are you sure this even compiles? I see `return condition;` from a `void` function (and if it wasn't `void` then `this.Close()` won't even be executed. Question: why aren't you properly using a VM here? Also note that (from what you're showing, at least) a plain `MessageBox` will do the job.

Comment: Use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` when you display the window. `ShowDialog()` won't return until the window has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `events` or `ShowDialog()`.

```
bool confirmed = false;
int id = 1;
promptWindow = new promptWindow(id, confirmed);
bool result = promptWindow.ShowDialog();

if (result)
{
    // confirm
}
else
{
    // not confirmed
}
```

And your window

```
public(int id, bool confirmed)
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
}

private void btnYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = true;
}

private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
}
```

The function `Window.ShowDialog()` will wait until the window has been closed. That means your code will wait in `ShowDialog()` line and you can check for result.
Function `Window.Show()` open the window and continue your code.

Another way is events: declare something like that on your Window

```
public event EventHandler<int> OnConfirmButton;
public event EventHandler<int> OnCancelButton;
```

On your buttons:

```
private void btnYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnConfirmButton?.Invoke(this, this.id);
}

private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnCancelButton?.Invoke(this, this.id);
}
```

And you can subscribe on your call:

```
bool confirmed = false;
int id = 1;
promptWindow = new promptWindow(id, confirmed);
promptWindow.OnConfirmButton += (sender, id) =>
{
    // do something when confirm
};

promptWindow.OnCancelButton += (sender, id) =>
{
    // do something when cancel
}

promptWindow.Show();
```

The `id` on arg is equal the id opened the window. This is just an example. Actually You do not need `events` on that case because you just need the result of window. But you can use on other cases, just follow the example.